# What's the easiest way to sort my sql results into a 3 column table?

Tags: php, html-table

I'm just going to include my whole "shopping.php" page code so you know where I'm coming from.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Shopping Page</title>
<style type="text/css">
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>
</head>
<body> 
    <form name="form1">
    <?php
    if (isset($_GET['cat'])) $cat=$_GET['cat'];
    else $cat = "fx";
    echo $cat;

    //1. Make a connection to the database
    $dbconn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","mydatabase1") 
      or die(mysqli_connect_error());
    $sql = "select productid,name,imagefile "
    ."from products "
    ."where categoryid='$cat'";
   echo $sql;


    //2. Run a query against the database
    $result = mysqli_query($dbconn,$sql) 
    or die(mysqli_error($dbconn));
```

...and this is the part where I want the results returned as a 3 column table:

```
//3. Return the results
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
{
    echo "<a href='order.php?prod=$row[0]'>$row[1]</a><br>";
    echo "<img src='images/products/$row[2]' "
    ."height=200px width =175px><br>";
}

 //4. Release the resources
 mysqli_free_result($result);

//5. Close the connection
mysqli_close($dbconn);
?>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Right now I get the results but it's just listed vertically. I tried a few different ways but I guess my noobness is getting the best of me. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I see is a two column table but you should make an `HTML` table.  (The  `<br>` tags are making it vertical)

```
$count = 0;
echo "<table><tr><th>Name</th><th>Image</th></tr>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
{
     if($count % 3 == 0){
         echo "<tr>";  //every third image make a new row
     }
     echo "<td><a href='order.php?prod=$row[0]'>$row[1]</a>";
     echo "<img src='images/products/$row[2]' "
     ."height=200px width =175px></td>";
     if($count % 3 == 2){
         echo "</tr>";  //every third image end the row
     }
     $count++;
}
echo "</table>";
```

**ALSO**

Please see this reference as you should bind your parameters if you are using `mysqli` or use PDO.  [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php/60496#60496)

**In response to your comment**

Added a count which adds in the table row tags every third image. The `%` is the modulus operator which give you the remainder on division.

Comment: Thanks. I definitely think you have me on the right track. What I was trying to get was 3 columns, each with the name and then the image underneath. Kind of like a simplified version of the "featured products" section on this site. [link](http://www.halloweenasylum.com/)

Comment: Oh I see that is what you mean by three columns, give me a minute.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I was trying to do the count thing before but my placement must have been off. Worked like a charm,

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in many ways. Using table is the better solution according to me. But if you want the easiest way than it will be using div. Use [columns Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_columns.asp) to make column. Use the following style:

```
<style>
.column3 {
    -webkit-column-count: 3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 3; /* Firefox */
    column-count: 3;
}
</style>
```

And wrap your result with this `div`

```
<div class="column3">
//Your Result
</div>
```